# Simplest Way To Get Full Function Referring Stack?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I have a cache handler function that processes functions placed in a queue by threads.

The cache handler is called when the console is idle.  I need to be able to know if a function is being processed by the cache handler, or if it's executing outside of the cache handler loop.

Some logic like so:

If cache handler in referring function stack, return True:

Here's the cache handler code:

```
# Processing all console items in queue.
def process_console_queue():
    log = StandardLogger(logger_name='console_queue_handler')

    if not CONSOLE_CH.CONSOLE_QUEUE:
        return


    set_console_lock()

    CONSOLE_CH.PROCESSING_CONSOLE_QUEUE.acquire()

    print('\nOutputs held during your last input operation: ')

    while CONSOLE_CH.CONSOLE_QUEUE:
        q = CONSOLE_CH.CONSOLE_QUEUE[0]
        remove_from_console_queue()
        q[0](*q[1], **q[2])

    CONSOLE_CH.PROCESSING_CONSOLE_QUEUE.release()
    release_console_lock()
    return
```

If that code calls a function which calls a function which calls a function.... (anywhere in that chain is called by process_console_queue) return True within the called function.

How's that done?

Comment: Instead of messing with the stack, why not just give the function another argument representing whether it's being called by the cache handler?

Comment: That would mean refactoring every function within the project with another arg.  There are 2 functions used through the whole project that need to process inputs a little differently if anywhere in the stack they are being called by the cache handler.  If I could test for that, 1-2 lines of code should do the trick without a complete refactoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a global `threading.local` object with an attribute, `in_cache_handler`?

Have the cache handler set the attribute to `True` on entry, and set it to `False` on exit.  Then any function that examines the attribute can tell whether the cache handler is somewhere below on the stack.

```
import threading
thread_local_object = threading.local()
thread_local_object.in_cache_handler = False

def cache_handler(...):
    try:
        thread_local_object.in_cache_handler = True
        ...
    finally:
        thread_local_object.in_cache_handler = False

def some_random_function(...):
    if thread_local_object.in_cache_handler:
        ...
    else
        ...
```

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, it is a flag, that says, "cache handler is running"?  To any function that looks for the flag? But if a thread calls a function while the cache handler is running it won't differentiate between a cache handler called function vs thread called function?  Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @Emily,  the `threading.local()` object is special.  It keeps separate copies of its attributes for each thread in the program.  So, the only time a function will see `thread_local_object.in_cache_handler==True` is when the cache handler is running *AND* the function is running in the same thread as the cache handler.  The only way both of those things can be true is if the function was directly or indirectly called by the cache handler.